# Why 'git push'(without -f) overwrites the remote history? [GitHub]

Tags: git, github, push, git-push, git-pull

I had one remote repository where I made some local commits(~6 commits) in let's say repo A and pushed those commits to GitHub and then I made some changes that I didn't commit or pushed.

Later I renamed that repo in GitHub and instead of update the references in the local one, I cloned it to another directory, let's say local repo B, and I made more commits(~30 commits) and pushed them and I deleted the repo B.

Then I noticed that the repo A has unpushed changes, I didn't pull the new commits, just committed the changes, and this is when the history diverged and pushed them with `$ git push`(without -f or --force) then got the following output:

```
...
remote: This repository moved. Please use the location:
remote: <new URL of the repo>
...
 + 3d93603...cec405b master -> master (forced update)
```

It replaced all the commits pushed from the local repo B

Later I managed to recover those commits with this using the [remote GitHub's reflog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61784279/7431197).

My question is why this happened? I didn't know git can overwrite the remote history without using `-f`, also that means `git pull` could rewrite the history like `git push` did it?

I never touched my push.default config, my version is 2.17.1, this is the [link to the GitHub API events of the repo](https://api.github.com/repos/EGA-SUPREMO/RPG-Game-template/events) and I haven't done any special changes to the .gitconfig if that helps.

Edit:
I replicated the experiment and now it gives me errors like torek pointed out, at this point, I just think this was caused by a bug.

Comment: `forced update` suggests that the push was indeed forced in some way ... either via settings or something else.

Comment: yeah, there isn't doubt about that, my question is why the push was forced? as I haven't done anything explicitly, to force the push.

Comment: The `remote:` prefix shows messages coming from the other Git. The "repository moved" message is telling you to update the URL stored in your own Git. Normally, right after that, you'd just get errors, but it looks like GitHub chose to turn your regular push into a force-push to *some* repository *somewhere* after that. Why—and where—are things you'd have to ask them.